# Homoglyphs REGEX detection and sql collation

Tags: mysql, regex, collation, sql-server-collation, homoglyph

I have a table containing some regexes.
By default the table was created using **utf8mb4_general_ci** collation.
Everything is fine until i try to add a regex containing homoglyphes like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/3tgFUf/1).
The regex // once stored in my database will simply never match.

What is causing this behavior ? I suspect the mysql table row collation to be in fault.
If so, what collation should be used to fix this ?

Does changing the collation will affect my other regex already stored in that table (more than 3k, but plain text, no homoglyphes) ?

Comment: Do you want that "T" to match the Greek "tau"?  That's not going to happen in the existing character sets.  Please provide a few examples of what you are try ing to do.

Comment: Your "this one" link has no example.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* to create a COLLATION that treats homoglyphs as equal, but I don't believe such exists in MySQL.

I tried these with the default collation:

```
42           66=x0042  [B]    L  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
CE92        914=x0392  [Β]    L  GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA
D092       1042=x0412  [В]    L  CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE
```

and got

```
SELECT 'Β' = 'B' AS 'beta:b', 'B' = 'В' AS 'b:Ve';
+--------+------+
| beta:b | b:Ve |
+--------+------+
|      0 |    0 |
+--------+------+
```

MySQL 8.0 updated its regexp processor to handle utf8mb4, so now

```
mysql> SELECT 'Β' RLIKE '[ΒBВ]';
+----------------------+
| 'Β' RLIKE '[ΒBВ]'    |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
```

So, with a bunch of 'character classes', you can build a regexp to check for any set of B-loolalikes, hence CRYPTO lookalikes.